# How to animate the figures in a Subplots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

I have written a code to explain the Superposition of waves. I paste my **Code** and **output** below. But problem is I just only create **static** graph....Things become more interesting if I can animate the waves (in my code :`subplot(211)`) and the correspoding result in `subplot(212)`. But till now I can only animate without subplots...and when I researched on internet about "animating in subplots using `matplotlib`" the results I found not so understandable to me and also different from my code in this case.

Can any one please help me in this regard? It would be better if the animation is based on my following code structure (of course the necessary change for subplot animation is appreciated). Thank you all.

**My Code**

```
#Composition of Waves
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('text', usetex = True)
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.style.use(['ggplot','dark_background'])

title = 'Composition of Waves'
#Parameters:
#a=Amplitude; w=Angular Frequency; phi = Phase Angle.

#Definition of the function:
def f(t,a,w,phi): 
    y = a*np.sin(w*t + phi)
    return y

t = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.001)

def create_plot(ptype):
    y1 = f(t,1,1,1)
    y2 = f(t,2,2,2)
    y = y1 + y2
    if ptype == 'waves':
        plt.plot(t, y1, label='$y=f_1(t)$')
        plt.plot(t, y2, label='$y=f_2(t)$')
    elif ptype == 'composition':
        plt.plot(t, y, label='$Composition$', color= 'm')

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)                                  
create_plot('waves')
plt.legend()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
#plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.title(title)

plt.subplot(212)
create_plot('composition')
plt.legend()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.xlabel('$t$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')

# Tweak spacing between subplots to prevent labels 
from overlapping
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

plt.savefig('composition_Waves.eps', format='eps', dpi=1000,bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

**Output**
[image: Code Output]

Here I want to animate the waves in different `w` and `phi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an animation is no different whether you have subplots or not. The only thing that matters is to keep a reference of your `Artist` objects (in this case the `Line2D` objects returned by `plt.plot()` to be able to modify their properties (data) in the animation function.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('text', usetex = False)
mpl.rc('font', family = 'serif')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.style.use(['ggplot','dark_background'])

title = 'Composition of Waves'
#Parameters:
#a=Amplitude; w=Angular Frequency; phi = Phase Angle.

#Definition of the function:
def f(t,a,w,phi): 
    y = a*np.sin(w*t + phi)
    return y

t = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.001)

def create_plot(ptype):
    y1 = f(t,1,1,1)
    y2 = f(t,2,2,2)
    y = y1 + y2
    arts = []
    if ptype == 'waves':
        l1, = plt.plot(t, y1, label='$y=f_1(t)$')
        l2, = plt.plot(t, y2, label='$y=f_2(t)$')
        arts = [l1, l2]
    elif ptype == 'composition':
        l3, = plt.plot(t, y, label='$Composition$', color= 'm')
        arts = [l3]
    return arts ## return the artists created by `plt.plot()`



my_lines = [] ## array to keep track of the Line2D artists
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)                                  
l = create_plot('waves') 
my_lines += l ## add artists to array
plt.legend()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
#plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.title(title)

plt.subplot(212)
l = create_plot('composition')
my_lines += l
plt.legend()
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.xlabel('$t$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')

# Tweak spacing between subplots to prevent labels from overlapping
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

print(my_lines)

def animate(i):
    ## in this examples, i takes values 0-10 by steps of 0.01 (the frames in the animation call)
    ## and will represent the frequency of the 2nd wave in the top subplot
    y1 = f(t,1,1,1)
    y2 = f(t,2,i,2)
    y = y1 + y2

    # update the content of the Line2D objects
    my_lines[1].set_ydata(y2)
    my_lines[2].set_ydata(y)
    return my_lines ## return updated artists

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=np.linspace(0,10,100))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ..but one problem occured when i save it as .mp4 file....My Legends on both the plots has been cropped in the video file saved....how to recover it

Comment: I use: ```anim.save('superpositionWaves.mp4', writer = 'ffmpeg', fps = 1, dpi=400,extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])```

Comment: try adding `plt.tight_layout()` before `plt.subplots_adjust(...)` in your code

Comment: How can I animate ```y1``` and ```y2``` simultaneously...?I tried:   ``` y1 = f(t,1,i,i*2)```
   ``` y2 = f(t,2,i,2)``` ..but it did not work...

Comment: You have to update the data in the Line2D object afterwards. ie add `my_lines[0].set_ydata(y1)`